# Why no space between operators in super and subscript

Tags: operator-space, default

By default operator space didn't come for super and subscripts which is correct in general. Refer the below code:

```
\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}

\[
a+b\sum+\int_{a+b\quad a=b}
\]

\end{document}
```

But any one can explain why this was fixed? I need to know this in detail...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default binary  operators such as + get a `\medmuskip` space either side, and relations such as `=` get `\thickmuskip` but this additional space is not added in scriptstyle and scriptscriptstyle settings. This is not configurable by TeX macros, it is built into the TeX sources as part of its math layout.

A `\quad` is just defined to be `\hskip1em` so it is not really a math-aware space it is 1em in the text font current before the math started. You can use 
`\nonscript\quad` if you really need to use a quad that vanishes in subscripts.

```
\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}

\[
a+b\sum+\int_{a+b\nonscript\quad a=b}
\]

\end{document}
```

or use a math space such as `\:` that adjusts to the subscript font size:

```
\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}

\[
a+b\sum+\int_{a+b\: a=b}
\]

\end{document}
```

`\:` is `\mskip\medmuskip`  and skips specified in `mu` units are relative to the current math style.

Comment: Sir, I meant that when the term a+b comes in normal online mode, then the operator space came before and after the + symbol, but if a+b comes in super or subscript then the operator space doesn't come for the symbol +, may I know why this was fixed...

Comment: @MadyYuvi oh I answered about the `\quad` but perhaps you were mainly asking about the +?   Questions about "Why" are not really answerable, the space around operators is not used in subscripts because Donald Knuth wanted it that way, it is not configurable from within TeX, it is part of tex-the-program.

Comment: @MadyYuvi I added a note about the space for + at the top of the answer.