# Spacing in mathastext package

Tags: math-mode, spacing, mathtools, newtx, mathastext

I have this MWE, using `mathastext` package.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage[italic,defaultmathsizes,symbolgreek]{mathastext}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\int^{n-1}_{2n+4n}{f_n(k,n)\,dx}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(-1)^k \sin k
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
3n+1=6n-\sum_{\substack{0 \le i \le m \\ 0 \leq j \leq n}} P(i, j) 
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

> Is it usual that this package have closer spacing? See the red rectangles.

Comment: Compare with and without `mathastext` the spacings on bin and rel operations are always tighter in sub- and subsubscript. (aka `\scriptstyle` and `\scriptscriptstyle`)

Comment: @daleif Very kind dailef I have seen: hence is it normal the spacing with this package for relation and binary symbols?

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/393106/3929

Comment: @campa I'd say so (I have no idea what is the proper method to mark a question as a duplicate)